# Attempted import error: 'useThemeProps' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/styles'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an error Attempted import error: 'useThemeProps' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/styles'. Yesterday's website worked, but when I deleted package-lock.json and node_modules after installation, the problem became. I don't know how I fix it. I updated a lot of material-ui/core versions.

my last package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.1.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.1.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.30",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.30",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.4",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.0.3",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import it from system according to [mui-system index file](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-system/src/index.js#L44).

`import { useThemeProps } from "@mui/system";`